# Formula for $A^n$ where $n \in \{1, \ 2, \ \cdots \ \}$ for the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && b \\ 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponentiation

Formula for $A^n$ where $n \in  \{1, \ 2, \ \cdots \ \}$ for the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && b \\ 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix}.$

Please help with the question if you can, it is for my Linear Algebra class and I cannot find anything close to an answer.

---

EDIT: As advised in comments, I have tried this for the first few $n$'s:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & b \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

$A^2=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & b \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & b \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2b \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

$A^3=A^2\cdot A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2b \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & b \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & b+2b \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3b \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Are you familiar with induction?

Comment: Try calculating the first few powers in terms of $b$ and look for a pattern. Then, prove that the pattern continues by induction.

Comment: Notice $A = I+B$ with $B^2 = 0$, we have 
$$\require{cancel} A^n = (I_2 + B)^n = I_2 + \binom{n}{1} B + \color{red}{\cancelto{0}{\color{gray}{B^2}}} \left( \binom{n}{2} I_2 + \cdots \right) =\cdots$$

Comment: mfl: no idea of induction! it is my first Linear Algebra class :/ my first non-calculus math class into my math major
Omnomnomnom: Thank you, I took the first 3 powers and then just wrote that A^n = (1 nb / 0 1)
achille hui: thank you but I don't know enough linear algebra to really understand how you are explaining it :/ one day..

Comment: Similar post: [Decompose this matrix as a sum of unit and nilpotent matrix.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134518/decompose-this-matrix-as-a-sum-of-unit-and-nilpotent-matrix)

Comment: @Michelle I have added computation of $A$, $A^2$, $A^3$ to your post. You say in your comment that [you have done this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452970/formula-for-an-where-n-in-1-2-cdots-for-the-matrix-a-beg#comment2959399_1452985), but you did not show the computation in your post. Adding your own attempts is one way of [providing context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960). Questions lacking context are likely to be closed. (Your question already has 4 close votes.)

Answer (score 6):

$$A^n=\begin{pmatrix}1&nb\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Suppose this is true until $n$. Then
$$A^{n+1}=A.A^n$$
Computing the right side almost completes the proof.

Comment: Yes this is a nice short introduction to induction.

Answer (score 5):

*Without induction:*

Write $A$ as $I+bE$, where $I$ is the unit matrix of rank $2$ and $E=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. As both matrices commute with each other, we can apply the binomial formula in the ring $M_2(\mathbf R)$, noting that $E^2=0$:
$$A^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk I^{n-k}b^kE^k=I+nbE=\begin{bmatrix}1&nb\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks! I am just starting in Linear Algebra, so I used your answer and wrote out my answer by just writing out A^1, A^2, and A^3 before writing that as the answer for A^n.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $A$ is the elementary matrix that adds $b$ times the second row to the first row. Then left multiplying by $A$ amounts to doing that operation, and the solution is now obvious.